# How to group by using Spark Scala in order to build nested DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this DataFrame:

```
val df: DataFrame = Seq(
("1", "1234 58", "SYSTEM_A", "5", "2022"),
("2", "1458 65", "SYSTEM_B", "2", "2021")
).toDF("id", "pseudo_id", "system", "number", "date")
```

I need to build a nested DataFrame using the `df` DataFrame with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pseudo_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- system: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to build it with:

```
val nestedDf: DataFrame = df
.groupBy("id", "pseudo_id", "system")
.agg(
  struct(
  "number",
  "date"
  ).as("version")
)
```

But I have obtained the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'number' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: The error message explains it pretty well, you have to use an aggregation expression for all columns that are not part of the group by. The question is what you really intend to do? Is it just about re-structuring the data / changing the schema or do you want to aggregate (deduplicate?) the data?

Comment: I just want to changing the schema of the inital data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [struct expression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#struct):

```scala
val df=...
val df2=df.selectExpr("id", "pseudo_id", "system", "struct(number, date) as version")
df2.printSchema()
```

Output:

```scala
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pseudo_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- system: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```